# Why has Hibernate created join table that prevents me emptying contents of table

Tags: java, hibernate

I have three Hibernate Entities:

- CoverArt
- Song

*Song* represent a song file (e.g mp3 file), 
*CoverArt* contains songs coverart, a song can have multiple pieces of coverart

Within *Song* I define link to *CoverArt* as:

```
@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
@JoinColumn(name = "recNo")
private List<CoverArt> coverArts;
```

Within *CoverArt* there is no link defined to *Song*, we just have

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Integer id;
```

The application works okay, except when I want to empty the Song and CoverArt entities.

It doesn't happen consistently but if I try and delete from *Song* first

```
e.g 
            String hql = String.format("delete from CoverArt");
            Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
            query.executeUpdate();

            hql = String.format("delete from Song");
            query = session.createQuery(hql);
            query.executeUpdate();

            session.getTransaction().commit();
```

I get exception:

> Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Referential integrity
>   constraint violation: "FK_CBUK1UQ1D0DQAA077XH16SRX2:
>   PUBLIC.SONG_COVERART FOREIGN KEY(COVERARTS_ID) REFERENCES
>   PUBLIC.COVERART(ID) (13)"; SQL statement:

and if I try the other way

```
String hql = String.format("delete from Song");
            Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
            query.executeUpdate();

            hql = String.format("delete from CoverArt");
            query = session.createQuery(hql);
            query.executeUpdate();
```

I get exception

> Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Referential integrity
>   constraint violation: "FK_4B4O39V3RSF1IWWRIX6QQQTLK:
>   PUBLIC.SONG_COVERART FOREIGN KEY(SONG_RECNO) REFERENCES
>   PUBLIC.SONG(RECNO) (1)"; SQL statement:

So its impossible to empty the tables, *CoverArt* entity only exists as part of a Song so I assumed their would only be a Foreign Key from a COVER_ART table to SONG table and expected I could delete everything from *CoverArt* without a problem, but there is an interim table created SONG_COVERART that has foreign keys to both tables preventing deletion.

What am I doing wrong (using Hibernate 4.3.11)

Comment: Probably because in a previous version of your code didn't have the JoinColumn annotation, and Hibernate thus created a join table for this association, that you filled, but forgot to delete.

Comment: @JBNizet I think you have it because I was not seeign the error myself, only some customers and I just switched on hibernate.show_sql and recreated database and there is no SONG_COVERART table, if you want to post an answer I will mark as correct.

Comment: @JBNizet ah, so recreatng db with  Configuration config = getInitializedConfiguration();
        config.setProperty(Environment.HBM2DDL_AUTO, "create"); wont fix problem because the troublesome table will still exists since Hibernate no longer knows about it, shod I just manually add a SQL drop statement ?

Comment: I would never use hbm2ddl to deal with an actual production database containing data. It's fine for quick prototyping, but not to maintain an actual database with data that must be properly migrated. FlywayDB and Liquibase are much better tools designed to do that.

Comment: @JBNizet I will look at that, but this is only an application db that usually does not need to be persisted for more than a few weeks at a time, please confirm that I wil have to do a seperate drop

Comment: Yes. "create" creates the tables you need. It doesn't care about other existing tables that are not needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably because in a previous version of your code didn't have the JoinColumn annotation, and Hibernate thus created a join table for this association, that you filled, but forgot to delete.